# How do I change the value of datetime when searching with datetime value in linq?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have some error occurs with this search function. I have two tables: employees and attendance. In table `Attendance` has `AddendanceDate` (datetime) column. I want to get the results absent lists of employee for today. For `DateTime.Today` result is OK, but I want to choose the search keyword with other dates.

How can I assign in this following code?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<AbsentReportsViewModel>> GetAllAbsentEmpAsync(DateTime date)
{
     var query = await (from e in _dbContext.Employees
                        join attt in _dbContext.Attendances
                             on e.Id equals attt.EmployeeId into eGroup
                        from eattt in eGroup.Where(a => a.AttendanceDate == DateTime.Today ).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where eattt.AttendanceDate == null
                        select new AbsentReportsViewModel
                               {
                                   JobId = e.JobId,
                                   EmpReportName = e.NameMM,
                                   DeptId = e.DeptId,
                                   RankId = e.CurrentRankId,
                                   DeptReportName = e.Department.DeptName,
                                   RankReportName = e.Rank.RankName,
                                   BarCode = e.Barcode,
                                   EmpReportId = e.Id,
                               }).ToListAsync();

    return query;
}
```

I tried :

```
... a.AttendanceDate == date.DefaultIfEmpty(),

... a.AttendanceDate == ((date).Year, (date).Month, (date).Day).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

I don't get the desired result.

Please help me to see the road. THANKS!

Comment: Does `.Where(a => a.AttendanceDate == date.Date)` work for you?

Comment: @Enigmativity   .Where(a => a.AttendanceDate == date.Date) Dont work for me also.

Comment: In what way does it not work when `DateTime.Today` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure that date is belong to curent date, better to use range filter. It will force SQL Server to use indexes. Also `LEFT JOIN` representation can be simplified:

```cs
var startDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
var endDate = startDate.AddDays(1);

var query = 
    from e in _dbContext.Employees
    from eattt in _dbContext.Attendances
        .Where(a => a.EmployeeId == e.Id && a.AttendanceDate >= startDate && a.AttendanceDate < endDate)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    where eattt.AttendanceDate == null
    select new AbsentReportsViewModel
    {
        JobId = e.JobId,
        EmpReportName = e.NameMM,
        DeptId = e.DeptId,
        RankId = e.CurrentRankId,
        DeptReportName = e.Department.DeptName,
        RankReportName = e.Rank.RankName,
        BarCode = e.Barcode,
        EmpReportId = e.Id,
    };
```

Comment: Thank You  Svyatoslav Danyliv. From your answer I got my result. Now I m using this code.